# Exact width input fields & text padding conundrum

Tags: css

What's the best solution for wanting exact width input fields (text), where you stipulate the padding too? Cross browser? I've never quite found the best way to do this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Nathan Smith's Formalize, cross browser forms are a complete pain, this really helps: http://formalize.me/

It's mostly CSS but has a bit of JS to make older IEs play nice.

Comment: Good link. I think I saw this a while back, and it was lost in the annals of history of my mind.